# C# DocuSign API: How to prefill form field data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I am trying to figure out a way to pre-fill form field data in a docusign form via the docusign api. Currently, I can successfully create my envelope via the following (with no prefilled data):

```cs
private EnvelopeDefinition CreateEvelope(ApplicationUser user)
{
    string recipientName = user.Name;
    string recipientEmail = user.Email;

    // file we want signed
    string templateId = "e19f3966-2c3e-4c47-a997-278e937dc85c";

    var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envDef.TemplateId = templateId;
    envDef.EmailSubject = "Some Email Subject";

    //null reference exception - envDef.Recipients is null
    var texttabs = envDef.Recipients.Signers.First().Tabs.TextTabs;

    //student role
    TemplateRole trole1 = new TemplateRole();
    trole1.Email = recipientEmail;
    trole1.Name = recipientName;
    trole1.RoleName = "Taxpayer";
    trole1.ClientUserId = user.Id;

    List<TemplateRole> roleList = new List<TemplateRole>() { trole1 };

    envDef.TemplateRoles = roleList;
    envDef.Status = "sent";

    return envDef;
}
```

It seems like via the templateId, I should be able to actually retrieve and fill out a template but I haven't seen a way to do this yet. How can I fill out the form field data? An example of the tabs/field data that is posted back to our Connect listener once the form is signed is the following:

```xml
<Type>Signer</Type>
<Email>test-signer@test.com</Email>
<UserName>Some User</UserName>
<RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
<Sent>2019-11-10T17:57:21.853</Sent>
<Delivered>2019-11-10T17:57:40.443</Delivered>
<Signed>2019-11-10T17:58:35.367</Signed>
<DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
<Status>Completed</Status>
<RecipientIPAddress>72.213.98.254</RecipientIPAddress>
<ClientUserId>1000</ClientUserId>
<CustomFields />
<TabStatuses>
    <TabStatus>
        <TabType>FirstName</TabType>
        <Status>Signed</Status>
        <XPosition>96</XPosition>
        <YPosition>288</YPosition>
        <TabLabel>First Name</TabLabel>
        <TabName>First Name</TabName>
        <TabValue>Rick</TabValue>
        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
    </TabStatus>
</TabStatuses>
<RecipientAttachment>
    <Attachment>
        <Data>IiPjx2YWx1ZT48L3ZhbHVlPjwvZmllbGQ+PG...</Data>
        <Label>DSXForm</Label>
    </Attachment>
</RecipientAttachment>
<AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
<FormData>
    <xfdf>
        <fields>
            <field name="FirstName">
                <value>Rick</value>
            </field>
        </fields>
    </xfdf>
</FormData>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TemplateRole has Tabs object, this is how you add a new one.

```
var tabs = new Tabs();
var textTab1 = new Text();
textTab1.Value = "test";
tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
tabs.TextTabs.Add(textTab1);
trole1.Tabs = tabs;
```

If you want to use an existing one, you will have to first read the information of the template by getting the template json so you will have all of it, and then use the tabLabel to match them.

Comment: How/where can I get the template json?

Comment: you need to use TemplatesApi and call the Get() method specifying the templateID